# I have to start Sunspot/Solr each time I run my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I just installed the [Sunspot](http://sunspot.github.com/) gem:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails'

group :development do
  gem 'sunspot_solr'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sunspot_test"
end
```

If I don't do `sunspot:solr:start` before doing `rails server` I get this error:

```
> OLR Request (1.3ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0xa9a3f6c>
> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0"
> encoding="UTF-8"?><add><doc><field name="id">Post 36</field><field
> name="type">Post</field><field
> name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field
> name="class_name">Post</field><field boost="5"
> name="title_text">sadads</field><field
> name="content_text">asdasdasdasdsadsdsd</field></doc></add>, headers:
> {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby},
> query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri:
> http://localhost:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: ,
> read_timeout: } ]
>      (0.4ms)  rollback transaction
>     Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 639ms
>     
>     Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
>       app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:41:in `create'
```

Each time I do a POST request (e.g. creating posts and votes in my app).

Is this a normal behavior of the gem? Is there of skipping or automating this step?

**EDIT:**

Here is the **post** **create action** and **model**, just in case:

```
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :title, boost: 5
    text :content
    text :replies do
      replies.map { |reply| reply.content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: If you really want to skip starting solr (slow dev machine perhaps), wrap the searchable block in `if Rails.env.production?`, or use delayed_job or some other queuing system to defer the indexing, but in general, add it to Foreman or have an initializer spin up the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a normal behavior of the gem? Is there of skipping or automating this step?

Yes, you need to start Solr if you want to use it, even if it's prepackaged. To make your life easier, you can use something like [Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html).